# Showing data usage in ios app

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Is there any way to show data usage (only for the current running application) in an iOS application?

I'm building an app which sends multiple files to a server and ultimately i would like to use data traffic displayed in a graph behind the upload view, but as far as i can see, there isn't a way to show current traffic.

Can anyone help?